# Highlight active nav menu, background-color:#fff works and color:#fff dont works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using an example that I see here in the forum to highlight the current nav menu.

I can do my active nav menu have `background-color:#fff` for example, but I'm not having sucess doing the `color:#fff`.
Why the `background-color:#fff` works and `color:#fff` doesn´t?

My html:

```
<section id="menu-container">
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            >
        </ul>
    </nav>   
</section>
```

Script jquery:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    var url = window.location.href; 

    $("#menu ul  li a").each(function() {

        if(url == (this.href)) { 
            $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
        }
    });
});         
</script>
```

Css:

```
.active{
    color:#FFF;
}
```

My whole css:

```
#menu-container{background:#243138; width:100%; height:62px;float:left; margin-top:15px; border-top: 4px solid #63F;}
#menu{width:960px; height:auto; margin:0 auto 0 auto;}
#menu ul{list-style-type:none;}
#menu ul li{float:left; height:62px; line-height:62px; font-size:20px; font-family:'bariol_regularregular';}
#menu ul li a{text-decoration:none; margin-right:5px; color:#ccc; display:block; height:62px; line-height:62px;padding:0 5px 0 5px; }
#menu ul li a:hover{color:#fff;}

active { color:#fff; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the anchor tag probably has a color assigned to it in the CSS. You can update your CSS to include the following:

```
li.active a { color:#fff; }
```

Comment: Thank you, but still dont work! I already did some expriences with my other css and dont work, just the background-color works. I update the post with my css. I tried to put #menu ul li a without color:#ccc and still dont work. This is very strange!

Comment: Probably a cascading issue. May need to be more specific. Try `#menu ul li.active a { color:#fff; }`

Comment: Thats it, thank you! I thought that because of this line $(this).closest("li").addClass("active"); , that we are adding a class .active to the li with href=url, i thought that in the css we could only to use .active!

Answer (score 0):

Or you need to add Class to the same **hyperlink**

check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7an3M/)

> remember as **I have applied the in document.ready()** so you have to
>   click the **run button** at top-left in jsfiddle, then only you will see
>   the active class effect of **home**  hyperlink

```
$("#menu ul li a").each(function() {    
      if(url == (this.href)) { 
          //$(this).addClass("active");
          $(this).addClass("active");
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

"Color" defines the color of text and it looks like you want to change the color of the background of some element. So the "background-color" property is the appropriate one.

If you want you can check it out [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_color)

and maybe add:

```
<div style="color:red; width:100px; height:100px; background-color:blue">
  <p> Hello </p>
</div>
```

so you can see how it works :)

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks,but i really want to change only the text-color to white, i have the text color black and I want to put white in the current nav menu!